# Using AngularUI for hot keys

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using the AngularUI keypress directive, but it's giving me problems.  I'm able to create a text field and attach a keypress event to it (basically it's exactly what's in the demo on the AngularUI page).

```
<textarea ui-keypress="{13:'keypressCallback($event)'}">
```

I'm trying to register hot keys for the buttons on my page, and it's not working when I attach the same ui-keypress event to the button (or the body of the page for that matter).  How can I get my hot keys working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build yours.
The way I did is to create 2 directives one for keypress and one for keyup

After you create your module (that I call yourapp), you create your directives.

```
yourapp.directive('keyPress', function () {
  return function (scope, elm, attrs) {
    elm.bind('keypress', function (e) {
      var intKey = (window.Event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
      if (intKey === attrs.key) {
        if (scope.theater === 1) {
          scope.$apply(attrs.keyPress);
        }
      }
    });
  };
});

yourapp.directive('keyUp', function () {
  return function (scope, elm, attrs) {
    elm.bind('keyup', function (e) {
      var intKey = (window.Event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
      if (intKey === attrs.key) {
        if (scope.theater === 1) {
          scope.$apply(attrs.keyUp);
        }
      }
    });
  };
});
```

So you can use it in this way:

```
<div key-press="doSomething()" key="13"> // enter
<div key-up="doSomething()" key="27"> // esc
```

**Note**: This `(window.Event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;` will make it cross browser.

Comment: What about alt + j for example?  Is the 'alt pressed' indicator in 'e' (the event)?

Comment: no idea about AngularUI. I would use `<textarea key-press="doSomething()" key="13">`

Comment: This is a good solution for a single hot key, but not for what I wanted (i.e. the ability to use 'alt-j' or 'ctrl-p' or something).  I've expanded this solution for my needs.

Comment: I think you can combine them or using "require:" and you create a third directive

Answer (score 2):

Try keyup or keydown, some keys don't work with keypress (ui-keyup, ui-keydown also exist).

Comment: This ened up working as well.  I did keydown and it works.  If I could accept two answers I would, but I've customized the other answer to fit my needs instead of using AngularUI.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad you got something working :-).
If you want a lighter-weight angular-ui, by the way, you can download a custom build with only the ui-key* directives with the 'Create a Build' button on http://angular-ui.github.com/ (the keypress module contains keydown, keyup, and keypress)